# How to save image on laravel storage?

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to make API for image url using laravel, but when I try to save image in storage always failed. I success to save image in public, but it can't be the image url. So I try to make image url using laravel storage, but always failed.

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => ['string', 'max:100'],
                'birthdate' => ['string'],
                'location' => ['string'],
                'gender' => ['required', 'string',],
                'phone_number' => ['numeric', 'unique:users'],
                'email' => ['string', 'max:255', 'email', 'unique:users'],
                'job_status' => ['string'],
                'skills' => ['string'],
                'bio' => ['string'],
                'profile_photo_path' => ['image'],
            ]);
    
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return ResponseFormatter::error([
                    'message' => 'Bad Request',
                    'errors' => $validator->errors()
                ], 'Bad Request', 400);
            }

            $skill = Skill::where('name', $request->skills)->first();
            if (empty($skill)){
                Skill::create([
                    'name' => $request->skills,
                ]);
            }


            Ability::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'skills_id' => $skill->id,
            ]);

            $data = $request->except('skills');
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($request->profile_photo_path) {
                $image = $request->profile_photo_path;
                $file_name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image->move(public_path('images'), $file_name);
                
                $path = "public/images/$file_name";
                $user->profile_photo_path = $path;
                try {
                    $storage_image = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('profile_photo_path'));
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return ResponseFormatter::error([
                        'message' => 'something error',
                        'errors' => $e
                    ], 'authentication failed', 500);
                }
                
                // $user['profile_photo_url'] = Storage::disk('public')->url($storage_image);
            }

            
            $user->update($data);
            

            return ResponseFormatter::success([
                'user' => $user
            ], "updated profile success");  
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return ResponseFormatter::error([
                'message' => 'something error',
                'errors' => $e
            ], 'authentication failed', 500);
        }
        
    }
```

`$storage_image = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('profile_photo_path'));` this line the problem

**this is the response**

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 500,
        "status": "error",
        "message": "authentication failed"
    },
    "data": {
        "message": "something error",
        "errors": {}
    }
}
```

I expect the success response like this

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "message": "updated profile success"
    },
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "johndoe",
            "username": "johndoe2",
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2023-06-23T22:06:46.000000Z",
            "birthdate": "2001-01-01",
            "phone_number": "0812345678901",
            "bio": "lorem lorem",
            "location": "new york",
            "job_status": "student",
            "two_factor_confirmed_at": null,
            "current_team_id": null,
            "profile_photo_path": "public/images/1687563096.jpg",
            "created_at": "2023-06-23T22:06:17.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-06-23T23:31:36.000000Z",
            "profile_photo_url": "http://localhost:8000/storage/public/images/1687563096.jpg"
        }
    }
```

How to fix that problem?